# How to build ZeroMQ on Xcode 5+ for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zeromq, xcode5.0.1

i am trying to build zmq 4.0.3 for iOS. i followed steps from [here](http://paolodenti.blog.com/2012/07/24/zeromq-ios/)

i added two headers `zmq.h` and `zmq_utils.h` to copy files in target aggregate build phase (iOS framework). but when i added this framework to other project i got errors -

> "std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned
>   long) const", referenced from:
>   zmq::socket_base_t::parse_uri(char const*,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >&) in
>   ZeroMQ-iOS(socket_base.o)   "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::compare(char
>   const*) const", referenced from:

now i m confused what happened with .hpp files. i havent added this to anywhere while in compiled source is  file witl all files having extension .cpp and .m.

1. if anyone had build this frame on xcode 5.0 so please give me instructions on how to build it.
2. how can i remove these linker error?

Comment: anyone please help me to resolve above problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you overcome from this problem?

Comment: Yes, after added other linker flag.